# Python write create file directly in FTP

Tags: python, ftp

I am looking to write a text directly to my FTP site from python without storing a temp file
on disk,
something like:

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.mysite.com')
ftp.login('un','pw')
ftp.cwd('/')
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.html', 'text to store', 'rb')
```

is this even possible?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) say:

> Store a file in binary transfer mode. *cmd* should be an appropriate `STOR` command: `"STOR filename"`. *file* is a file object (opened in binary mode) which is read until EOF using its `read()` method in blocks of size *blocksize* to provide the data to be stored…

So, you need to give it a file-like object with an appropriate `read` method.

A string is not a file-like object, but an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) is. So:

```
import io
bio = io.BytesIO(b'text to store')
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.html', bio)
```

---

Also, notice that I didn't pass that `'rb'` argument. The third parameter to `storbinary` is *blocksize*, and `'rb'` is obviously not a valid block size.

---

If you need to work with Python 2.5 or earlier, see Dan Lenski's answer.

And if you need to work with Python 2.6-2.7, and performance of the file-like object is important (it isn't here, but there are some cases where it might be), and you only care about CPython, use his answer but with [`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) in place of `StringIO`. (Plain `StringIO` is slow in 2.x, and `io.BytesIO` is even slower before around 3.3.)

Comment: Worked for me but I had to encode the string as BytesIO requiresa bytes-like object. So: `bio = io.BytesIO('text to store'.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: @iomihai Well, in this case, you could just use a bytes literal, instead of using a str literal and encoding it. But yeah, I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using a [`StringIO` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), which quacks like a file but is just a string?

```
from ftplib import *
import StringIO

ftp = FTP('ftp.mysite.com')
ftp.login('un','pw')
ftp.cwd('/')
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.html', StringIO.StringIO('text to store'))
```

EDIT: [@abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25735214/20789) is the Python3 equivalent. Mine is the Python2 version.

Comment: `io` works just as well in 2.6 and 2.7 as it does in 3.x. So there's no reason to use the old version unless you need 2.5 compatibility.

Comment: Well, I held onto 1.5 compatibility until 2.4 added some feature I just couldn't live without, so I can understand that…

Comment: [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) has been tempting me to bite the Unicode bullet and go to 3.x for a while now.

Comment: Not that I ever want to take away anyone's motivation to upgrade, but… `lru_cache` is pure-Python, it almost works out-of-the-box with 2.6+, and there's a backport to 2.4+. But `yield from`, `pip` bootstrap, built-in `venv`, `tracemalloc`, `asyncio`, `selectors`, bug fixes and optimizations that will never be backported, saner and more detailed exception hierarchy, chained exceptions, `importlib`, C functions with actual argspecs, improved `inspect`, `concurrent.futures`, … Plus, once you bite the bullet, proper Unicode is a plus, not a stumbling block.

Comment: Absolutely, proper Unicode is a clear win both for the programmer and the users... just one that I haven't fully wrapped my head around yet. `yield from` and `importlib` are among the others that have tempted me... `lru_cache` was just a recent example of my gnawing Py3k envy.