# How to write pandas dataframe to csv/xls on FTP directly

Tags: python

How to create a .csv or .xls file on ftp directly from Pandas dataframe as I do not want to create one on local machine and then push it on ftp. Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) say:

> Store a file in binary transfer mode. *cmd* should be an appropriate `STOR` command: `"STOR filename"`. *file* is a file object (opened in binary mode) which is read until EOF using its `read()` method in blocks of size *blocksize* to provide the data to be stored…

So, you need to give it a file-like object with an appropriate `read` method.

A string is not a file-like object, but an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) is. So:

```
from ftplib import *
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas
import io

ftp = FTP('ftp.mysite.com')
ftp.login('un', 'pw')
ftp.cwd('/')
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
your_pandas_df.to_csv(buffer)
text = buffer.getvalue()
bio = io.BytesIO(str.encode(text))

ftp.storbinary('STOR filename.csv', bio)
```

for reference you can refer [Python write create file directly in FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735134/python-write-create-file-directly-in-ftp)

Comment: Hi Anurag, thanks for very quick answer.  I can create the file with this line:session.storbinary('STOR myfile', StringIO.StringIO(ResultsToFtp.to_csv('testfile'))) but don't know why the file is always empty. I have checked the dataframe ResultsToFtp has data inside but for some reason file is empty with None on cell A1

Comment: first try to write file into local system (if possible). I think this will give clear picture is there some problem in `FTP` or producing file like object (i.e `StringIO` object)

Comment: I did it locally from the same dataframe and works fine

Comment: use `ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile', StringIO.StringIO(your_pandas_df))` because [python stringIO documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) as it need memory object not a file. and `dataframe.to_csv` does return anything

Comment: can I use something to reformat it in more organized way because the csv or xls file looks like string of dataframe in one col in excel

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'   pops up this error

Comment: buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
Hi, this is working perfectly now :)
ResultsToFtp.to_csv(buffer)
text = buffer.getvalue()
bio = io.BytesIO(str.encode(text))
session.storbinary('STOR test'+xxx+'.csv', bio)

Comment: For someone like me, 
In python 3, you need to import io, StringIO is gone 
for custom file name, 
'STOR ' + your_file_name