# How to export csv to server location in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I need to export csv to server location,
lets suppose my server location is :
http//5.6.80.9:8079/ExportedFiles/Files/
I Tried:

```
df.to_csv(r"http//5.6.80.9:8079/ExportedFiles/Files/ filename.csv", index=False)
```

its not working.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248832/how-to-transfer-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-on-sftp-using-paramiko-library-in-pytho

Comment: [Related Questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+save+csv+to+remote+server+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk03bs25FTGH9mQyqq2H925bWovX6cQ:1596094018287&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxsfPHufTqAhWwCTQIHdqZBpAQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=975)