# Numpy Savetxt to ftp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to save the txt file directly to a ftp location instead of localmachine. I have found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073355/7987118), but I would like to use numpy.savetxt()

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you want to use FTPlib? I don't think it's possible with only `savetxt` but if you insist using numpy, numpy has DataSource function that can read files from remote that you can try: https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/input-and-output/datasource.php

Comment: @tyz I can use FTPlib, I'm not sure how to use this library with savetxt

Comment: `savetxt` works with an opened file, so presumably will work with anything that has an `write` method.  `savetxt` is written in python, so you can read the code, and adapt it as needed.  Basically it iterates on the array rows, formats them and writes them.